# Error happens when i use 'use facebook' in my facebook application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created an application and security token and app id were taken.
And domain has been set to localhost, siteURL localhost/facebook (where i've php sdk)

This is the code i took from facebook developer itself, but i'm getting an error at line no 1 where code is

use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithgraphapi/4.0.0

I'm confused with developer document. Actually i feel which is not much helpful for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without knowing the error, but i assume you don´t have PHP 5.4+ on your server. The PHP SDK needs 5.4+.